# Is it possible to use something other than id selectors in a checkbox hack?

Tags: css, css-selectors

This just seems so simple, but I'm not even sure it's possible.  I've posted on this project here before, but after coming up against this issue, I'd abandoned it for about a month.  So it goes without saying, I think, that I would deeply appreciate any advice I can get.  Thank you all in advance; I know questions like this are generally beneath the skill-level of folks here, but I've yet to find somewhere to find more reliable advice as I try to learn CSS.

Essentially: **I need to integrate a relatively simple checkbox hack into a CMS, but the CMS strips id selectors**. Hence, code that *ought* to look something like this:

`<input type="checkbox" name="thisisaname" id="thisisanid"><label class="thisisanid" for="thisisanid">Type 1</label>`

...ends up like this:

`<input type="checkbox" name="thisisaname"><label class="thisisanid" for="thisisanid">Type 1</label>`

Predictably, this breaks everything, and ostensibly any adaptation appears to be impossible. There is no CMS-specific alternative like `ClientID=`.  Neither jQuery nor JavaScript are available to me (they're also stripped out by the CMS).

I am in a quandary.  I'm not experienced in CSS, and this CMS (which I *must* use, unfortunately) is making everything ten times harder than it ought to be. So, here's my question: Is there a recommended means of overcoming limitations like this that I've missed in my research?

And... is it *maybe* possible to mimic this behavior using [attribute|=value] selectors in lieu of id?  Honestly, I'm not even sure if this is worth pursuing, so I haven't, but could there be something to this?  Or am I just spinning my gears?

This is the pared down version of the code I've been trying to integrate, by the way:

```css
.wrap { display:flex; width:50%; vertical-align:top;}
.wrap aside {vertical-align:top;}
.wrap label {white-space:nowrap; display: block;}

.checker {background: red; padding: 50px; vertical-align:top;}
.checker {margin: 10px; display: inline-block; position: relative;}

.wrap input { display: none; }
input:checked ~ main .checker { display: none; }

#check1cont:checked ~ aside .check1cont,
#check2cont:checked ~ aside .check2cont { color: blue; }

#check1cont:checked ~ main .check1,
#check2cont:checked ~ main .check2 {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <input type="checkbox" name="cont" id="check1cont">
  <input type="checkbox" name="controllers" id="check2cont">
  
  <aside>
    <label class="check1cont" for="check1cont">Check 1</label>
    <label class="check2cont" for="check2cont">Check 2</label>
  </aside>
  
  <main>
    <figure class="checker check1">CHECK 1</figure>
    <figure class="checker check2">CHECK 2</figure>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the structure is known and will not change, you can rely on `nth-child` / `nth-of-type` to select your elements without even using classes. The other trick is to make the input positioned above the labels so you can trigger the checked without the need of the `for`.

```css
.wrap { display:flex; width:50%; vertical-align:top;position:relative;}
.wrap aside {vertical-align:top;}
.wrap label {white-space:nowrap; display: block;}

.checker {background: red; padding: 50px; vertical-align:top;}
.checker {margin: 10px; display: inline-block; position: relative;}

.wrap input { position:absolute;width:50px;opacity:0;z-index:1; }
.wrap input:nth-of-type(2) {top:17px;}

input:checked ~ main figure { display: none; }

input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ aside label:nth-of-type(1),
input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ aside label:nth-of-type(2) { color: blue; }

input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ main figure:nth-of-type(1),
input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ main figure:nth-of-type(2) {display: inline-block;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <input type="checkbox" name="cont">
  <input type="checkbox" name="controllers">

  <aside>
    <label class="check1cont" for="check1cont">Check 1</label>
    <label class="check2cont" for="check2cont">Check 2</label>
  </aside>

  <main>
    <figure class="checker check1">CHECK 1</figure>
    <figure class="checker check2">CHECK 2</figure>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!  The notion of using nth-of-type is beautifully elegant, but I'm not sure it will work for the final product as the structure is quite variable.  Nonetheless, it's a much better idea than anything I've even broached, so again, *thank you so much*.  FWIW, this is what the final will essentially look like: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBKGew (this hasn't been cleaned up, obviously; it's my working copy).  And out of curiosity... what would it look like to position input above the labels?  I've seen it referenced as an option, but I've never seen it in action.